# HighCharts full width issue when loading page

Tags: jquery, highcharts

I'm using Highcharts column chart and I want it to be 100% width responsive chart. The container is a simple `<div>` with no any formatting. When the document loads, the chart is always fixed width 600x400px size. If I resize window or switch to another browser tab, the chart fills the width and becomes responsive full width chart just like I wanted. If I reload page, it's fixed width again. So I tried to set width:900 in chart. But it made the chart window screen fixed, not resizeable. How to make the chart become full width on page load also?

Comment: You have to fix the width of the graph **and** its container

Comment: try using minimum width e.g (min-width: 310px;) instead of width

Comment: You should set width:100% for your chart container in CSS (not highcharts). Do you use bootstrap ?

Answer (score 0):

Once your chart getting load, you can put below code at the end and it will work like a miracle.

```
setTimeout(() => {
    window.dispatchEvent(new Event('resize'));
}, 10);
```